# How to add LabelBinarizer columns to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have recently started working with LabelBinarizer by running the following code. ([here are the first couple of rows of the CSV file that I'm using](https://file.io/MFcUOI)):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plot


#--------------------------------

label_conv = LabelBinarizer()
appstore_original = pd.read_csv("AppleStore.csv")

#--------------------------------

lb_conv = label_conv.fit_transform(appstore["cont_rating"])
column_names = label_conv.classes_

print(column_names)        
print(lb_conv)
```

I get the lb_conv and the column names. Therefore:

*how could I attach `label_conv` to `appstore_original` using `column_names` as the column names?*

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
lb = LabelBinarizer()

df = pd.read_csv("AppleStore.csv")

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(df["cont_rating"]),
                          columns=lb.classes_, 
                          index=df.index))
```

to make sure that a newly created DF will have the same index elements as the original DF (we need it for joining), we will specify `index=df.index` in the constructor call.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: could you just explain me what does the `index=`do